# Gitlab CI is ignoring ci.skip

Tags: node.js, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to create a pipeline on Gitlab CI that increments the app version everytime we get a commit on master. But it is ignoring my ci.skip command and I don't know why.

The yaml file is this one:

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'master'

before_script:
  - git config --global user.email "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
  - git config --global user.name "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
  - git remote set-url origin https://push:$PUSH_KEY@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git

auto_release:
  image: node:10
  script:
    - yarn
    - yarn release
    - git push --follow-tags origin HEAD:master -o ci.skip
    - echo "Done!"
```

So everytime I push a new commit it gets locked inside an eternal loop that commits a new version and commits a new version over and over again. The only way to stop is manually cancelling the jobs.

Pleas note: When we use the image `node` or `node:latest` it works, but our version requires `node:10` otherwise it will break and won't build.

Comment: Could you please try adding **[ci skip]** or **[skip ci]**, to your commit message. I hope you have tried but just give it a try if not

Comment: @Sourav I tried to do it, but it did't worked

Answer (score 0):

`node:10` is a very old image. The git version it contains does not support push options (at least with the shorthand `-o`), so that's why the push triggers the next CI build.

Check the git version in the image - if it's 2.10 to 2.17 you can use `--push-option=ci.skip`. If it's still an older version, you need to create your own docker image that contains node version 10 and a modern git version.